# I have facing flicker and flashing in screen recorded video with ubuntu 16.4 dell laptop

Tags: xubuntu

I tried to record my screen as video. But I unable because recorded video become flicker and flashing. You can review using video [click for video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUQ1eKUppxJ-LLcFo7F2XicywH1LX2lj/view?usp=sharing)

I have show you our system configuration. you can review using screenshot [Please see system configutaion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n91hZ.png)

Please help us to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The video link you provided does not work for me. Can you fix that please?

Are you running Xorg or Wayland? If you are on Wayland I don't think screen recording is possible except by using a tool specific to your compositor.

For Xorg, have you tried to add the `TearFree` option to your Xorg config as follows? In the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    # attempting to solve screen recording glitches
    Option      "TearFree"  "true"
EndSection
```

[Source](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen/issues/171#issuecomment-278757840)

Another option to attempt is using the `modesetting` driver instead of the `intel` one. Define an Xorg config like this one in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-graphics.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "modesetting"
    Option      "AccelMethod"    "glamor"
EndSection
```

[Source](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen/issues/171#issuecomment-324943191)

Sorry for all the questions but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment your question.

On some Linux distributions, you might need to change `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` as identified in the comments.

Comment: The video link you provided does not work for me. Can you fix that please?
## I have shown you how recorded video output.

For Xorg, have you tried to add the TearFree option to your Xorg config as follows?<br/>
## Sorry Olivier but these files not available in my directory. <br/>
[Please view directory files](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1YhuKdvKQzFstA--I7KK84Sjr5ApmRcL1)

Comment: Sorry last image link is not working correct image link here [please view directory files] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmDARxfxgZgepnls-NdWU_jNEziSgktr/view)

Comment: What about this folder `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`?

Comment: Thanks, Olivier it working for us. You can review using [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oRRDkYmh-nhlC1KWoCoYDTZ858fPOu1/view). You have saved my lot of time and money.

Comment: Can you upvote and accept the answer, please?

Comment: I already try for it but due to the insufficient reputation, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Remove xf86-video-intel

Worked for me.

I guess the relevant line is `sudo apt-get remove xf86-video-intel`. I haven't an Ubuntu to test right now however.